# How to iterate through a list and make lists of the elements

Tags: clojure

I am trying to convert logical functions in clojure. I want the user to be able to type in `(convert '(and x y z)` to produce `(nor (nor x) (nor y) (nor z)`. So I am creating a list with first element `nor`, and then trying to make the rest of the elements lists that are created when going through a `for` loop. However the `for` loop just combines all the lists, and keeps the `nor` outside of it. I also want to know how to skip the first element in the list but that's not my priority right now. I'm kinda new to clojure and can't figure out how to just return all of the lists to be put into the bigger list. The `not` and `or` function aren't related to the problem.

```
(defn lookup
  "Look up a value, i, in map m and returns the result if it exists. 
  Otherwise returns i."
  [i m]
  (get m i i))

(defn makelist
    [l]
    (for[i[l]] (list 'nor i)))

(defn convert
  [l]
  (let [p1 (first l)]
    (cond
      (= p1 'not) (map (fn [i] (lookup i '{not nor})) l)
      (= p1 'or) (list 'nor (map(fn [i] (lookup i '{or nor})) l))
      (= p1 'and) (list 'nor (makelist l))
      :else (print "error"))))
```

The output I get is `(nor ((nor (and x y z))))`. The output I want is `(nor (nor and) (nor x) (nor y) (nor z)`. I don't want the `(nor and)` either but until I can figure out how to skip the first element I just want to be able to separate the lists out.

Comment: Can you show (or explain) the definition of `lookup`?

Comment: @jas I just added it in there. However the part that uses lookup works fine, I'm just not sure how to go about doing the add connective.

Comment: Our professor told us in class how to ignore a list element when using let. Use the underscore to indicate an element that you don’t care about. let [[_ x] l] binds x to the second element in the list l, ignoring the first. Be careful what you post to SO. Posting your literal homework assignment is a good way to find yourself in trouble. You are approaching this differently than I did, but it looks like this could work.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems that I can see:

1. `makelist` has `(for [i [l]] ...)` so it only produces a single item where `i` is bound to the whole of the incoming list `l` -- what you want here is `(for [i l] ...)` so that each element of `l` is processed,
2. `convert`'s clause for `and` creates a list with two elements: `nor` and the result of `(makelist l)` -- what you want here is `(cons 'nor (makelist l))` so that you get a list with `nor` as the first element and then all of the elements of the result of calling `makelist`.

I haven't checked the other two parts of `convert` to see whether you have similar errors, but with the two changes above `(convert '(and x y z))` will produce `(nor (nor and) (nor x) (nor y) (nor z))`

Comment: Thank you, that helps a ton. I couldn't find anywhere how to iterate through the list correctly, I was using syntax for vectors, and actually as of reading this I realized it wasn't working properly.

Answer (score 0):

just for fun: i would mentally expand and generalize your task to rewriting data structures according to some rules, so you could declare (possibly recursive) rewrite rules to transform any input to any desired output in general. (and to practice clojure)

let's start with simple conversion function:

```
(defn convert [rules data]
  (if-let [res (some (fn [[condition rewrite]]
                       (when (condition data) (rewrite data)))
                     rules)]
    res
    data))
```

it finds first rule that suits your input (if any) and applies it's transformation function:

```
(def my-rules [[sequential? (fn [data] (map #(convert my-rules %) data))]
               [number? inc]
               [keyword? (comp clojure.string/upper-case name)]])
#'user/my-rules

user> (convert my-rules [:hello :guys "i am" 30 [:congratulate :me]])
;;=> ("HELLO" "GUYS" "i am" 31 ("CONGRATULATE" "ME"))
```

with this approach, your rules would look something like this:

```
(def rules
  [[(every-pred coll? (comp #{'not} first)) (fn [data] (map (partial convert [[#{'not} (constantly 'nor)]]) data))]
   [(every-pred coll? (comp #{'or} first)) (fn [data] (map (partial convert [[#{'or} (constantly 'nor)]]) data))]
   [(every-pred coll? (comp #{'and} first)) (fn [[_ & t]] (cons 'nor (map #(list 'nor %) t)))]])
#'user/rules

user> (convert rules '(and x y z))
;;=> (nor (nor x) (nor y) (nor z))
```

ok it works, but looks rather ugly. Still we can elimnate some repetitions introducing couple of basic functions for checkers and transformers:

```
(defn first-is 
  "returns a function checking that the input is collection and it's head equals to value"
  [value]
  (every-pred coll? (comp #{value} first)))
```

transforming your rules to:

```
(def rules
  [[(first-is 'not) (fn [data] (map (partial convert [[#{'not} (constantly 'nor)]]) data))]
   [(first-is 'or) (fn [data] (map (partial convert [[#{'or} (constantly 'nor)]]) data))]
   [(first-is 'and) (fn [[_ & t]] (cons 'nor (map #(list 'nor %) t)))]])
#'user/rules

user> (convert rules '(and x y z))
;;=> (nor (nor x) (nor y) (nor z))
```

and then introducing replacing rewrite rule:

```
(defn replacing
  ([new] [(constantly true) (constantly new)])
  ([old new] [#{old} (constantly new)]))
```

leading us to

```
(def rules
  [[(first-is 'not) (fn [data] (map (partial convert [(replacing 'not 'nor)]) data))]
   [(first-is 'or) (fn [data] (map (partial convert [(replacing 'or 'nor)]) data))]
   [(first-is 'and) (fn [[_ & t]] (cons 'nor (map #(list 'nor %) t)))]])
```

now we can see that there is a demand on a function, transforming every item in collection. let's introduce it:

```
(defn convert-each [rules]
  (fn [data] (map #(convert rules %) data)))

(def rules
  [[(first-is 'not) (convert-each [(replacing 'not 'nor)])]
   [(first-is 'or) (convert-each [(replacing 'or 'nor)])]
   [(first-is 'and) (fn [[_ & t]] (cons 'nor (map #(list 'nor %) t)))]])

user> (convert rules '(or x y z))
;;=> (nor x y z)

user> (convert rules '(and x y z))
;;=> (nor (nor x) (nor y) (nor z))
```

now it is much better, but the last clause is still kind of ugly. I can think of introducing the function that transforms head and tail with separate rules and then conses transformed head and tail:

```
(defn convert-cons [head-rules tail-conversion]
  (fn [[h & t]] (cons (convert head-rules h) (tail-conversion t))))

(defn transforming [transformer]
  [(constantly true) transformer])

(def rules
  [[(first-is 'not) (convert-each [(replacing 'not 'nor)])]
   [(first-is 'or) (convert-each [(replacing 'or 'nor)])]
   [(first-is 'and) (convert-cons [(replacing 'nor)]
                                  (convert-each [(transforming #(list 'nor %))]))]])

user> (convert rules '(and x y z))
;;=> (nor (nor x) (nor y) (nor z))
```